# Wordpress: Show items in media library for specific user role only

Tags: php, wordpress, media

in Wordpress it is possible to restrict media libraries access with this snippet in the functions.php:

```
add_filter('ajax_query_attachments_args', 'user_group_library_permission');

function user_group_library_permission($query) {

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

if $user_id && !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts')) {
    $query['author'] = $user_id;
}
return $query;
```

So, every user which uploads data in the media library will see their own files.

Is it possible to advance this functionality? I have two custom user roles and every user with this user role should see which data is uploaded in the library, e.g. all members of group A should see the members uploads and all users in group B should see what the users in A had uploaded.

Comment: Directly querying for user roles is probably not possible at this point. If you don’t want to get into too complex query manipulation, then it would probably be easiest if you got the user ids of all users in the respective group at this point first, and then replaced manipulating `$query['author']` with specifying an array of ids for `author__in` instead (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#author-parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I have a little struggle with this query. Maybe you have an answer. This is the code I use instead of `query['author]`: $users = new WP_Query( array( 'author__in' => array( 8, 9, 10 ) ) );` When I do this the function return nothing and the library in frontend is empty. Whats is the return value of this function? I don't understand it.

Comment: No, that’s not what I meant, you don’t need to create an instance of WP_Query yourself, I was just referring to that documentation page, because it explains the syntax/possible conditions. `$query['author'] = …` should be replaced with `$query['author__in'] = $array_of_user_ids;`

Comment: Do you mean this? `$users_sw = [ 8, 9, 10, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33 ];` `$query['author__in'] = $users_sw;` I am not sure.

Comment: Yes, something like that should work.

Comment: Mhhm, I think that didn't work like expacted. When I get logged in with a user which ist not noted in the Array, i got all the files shown which where uploaded by the other group. Furthermore when I upload a file with this user, this file is not shown in the library.
Only with the array $users_sw it works.

Comment: I fixed the issue with the switch-case statement where i check the current user id and assign it to the users-id array. Thanks a lot for your advices @CBroe !

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this if-else-condition.

```
$users_sw = [ 8, 9, 10, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32, 33 ];
$users_so = [ 11, 12, 13 ];

if ( !current_user_can('activate_plugins') && !current_user_can('edit_others_posts') ) {

    if ( $users_sw ) {
        $query[ 'author__in' ] = $users_sw;
    
    } else if ( $users_so ) {    
        $query[ 'author__in' ] = $users_so;
    
    }
    return $query;
}
return;
```

When I run the programm it returns always the the first condition. But the problem is that i am logged in with the user with the id 11 and in media library are the files  which where uploaded by the user with the id 8 are shown. But that should be restricted.